# Making a full bootable Ubuntu USB broke GRUB2 on my dual-boot Ubuntu laptop

Tags: boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu with a Live DVD to the USB drive, as a bootable install that would be faster than the Live DVD.
I already had Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Windows 10 on my computer's eMMC. I found after restarting that GRUB was broken. Instead of bringing me to the boot menu, it brought me to the grub command-line.

After that, with another USB drive, I made a SuperGrub2Disk. I'm currently booted in my Ubuntu install that was on my computer's eMMC through that. I already tried to do `grub-install /dev/mmcblk0p1` as that's my EFI partition where GRUB was before this happened. However, it can't find the partition. Can you guys help me with this?

When I do `df -h` it shows the output shown below, I hope this helps.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           380M  1.8M  379M   1% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p5   19G   12G  5.8G  68% /
tmpfs           1.9G   29M  1.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      9.2M  9.2M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop1      157M  157M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1193
/dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/loop3       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop4       97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9436
/dev/loop5       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop6      256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop7      2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop8      241M  241M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24
/dev/loop9       50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/433
/dev/loop10      30M   30M     0 100% /snap/snapd/8140
/dev/loop11      28M   28M     0 100% /snap/snapd/7264
/dev/loop12     164M  164M     0 100% /snap/spotify/41
/dev/loop13      49M   49M     0 100% /snap/minetest/1521
/dev/loop14      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/mari0/6
/dev/loop15      63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop16      50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/467
/dev/loop17      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/mari0-ce/9
tmpfs           380M   32K  380M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk0p3   39G   25G   14G  64% /media/dexter/F6184FC7184F8599
/dev/mmcblk0p1  256M   33M  224M  13% /boot/efi
```

Note that `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is my EFI partition, `/dev/mmcblk0p3` is my Windows 10 partition, and `/dev/mmcblk0p5` is the Ubuntu partition.

By the way, I only installed Ubuntu on my laptop a few days ago, and I’ve already installed a lot of apps and already have a lot of stuff, so I would rather not reinstall Ubuntu.

Update: Boot Repair fixed it!

Comment: I already read up a bit on that, and when I tried to install it, it couldn’t add it. I was booted from the Live DVD at the time, so I may have just forgotten to  connect to my Wi-Fi.

Comment: I also meant to say that I was trying to install Ubuntu to my USB because it’s faster than my Live DVD.

Comment: I’m in my regular Ubuntu that’s on my eMMC now, thanks to SuperGrub2Disk. I installed and ran Boot Repair, and it said 

“LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from live-CD (or live-USB)”

Comment: I don’t have an option for BIOS compatibility in my UEFI firmware. I’m on an ASUS laptop with the ASUS BIOS Utility - EZ Mode.

Comment: Boot repair apparently repaired it, after activating the “Seperate boot/efi partition” option. There is an advanced mode in my UEFI firmware, but either way, there was no legacy mode options in my UEFI firmware. Now I’m going to reboot my laptop and see if it fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check out launchpad bugs 1396379,and 1173457 and add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list at the top.

Comment: We cannot seem to get any traction on fix for this bug. More that complain the better. Also see work around during install in #23 & 26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379